# How to map external touch screen to ignore laptop in multimonitor setup?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

Kubuntu 20.04 with extended display. Laptop screen has no touch. External screen is a touchscreen.  When touching the center of the external screen, the mouse points at the border between two screens.  It's calculated as if the touchscreen's width is the width of both screens together.

How can I make the touchscreen fit only the external screen?  Also, it's a portable screen.  So I would like to make the change permanent between disconnects.

```
sza@sza-Lenovo-ThinkBook-15-IIL:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M705                             id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K750                             id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech K750                             id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]

sza@sza-Lenovo-ThinkBook-15-IIL:~$ xinput list-props 9
Device 'G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP':
        Device Enabled (172):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (174): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix (312):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Calibration Matrix Default (313):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (295):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (296):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (297):        0, 0
        Device Node (298):      "/dev/input/event4"
        Device Product ID (299):        10900, 22093

sza@sza-Lenovo-ThinkBook-15-IIL:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   ...
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 195mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    29.97  
   ...
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the following **`xinput`** option to be of interest:

```
--map-to-output device crtc
    Restricts  the  movements  of  the absolute device to the RandR
    crtc. The output name must match a currently  connected  output
    (see  xrandr(1)).  If  the  NVIDIA binary driver is detected or
    RandR 1.2 or later is not available, a Xinerama output  may  be
    specified as "HEAD-N", with N being the Xinerama screen number.
    This option has no effect on relative devices.
```

Based on info you've provided, the following command may do what you need:

```
xinput --map-to-output "G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP" DP-1
```

If this command does what you want, you can set up `udev` to run it whenever the touch screen is connected. However, `xinput` will not work when called directly because `udev` is a system service that runs outside of X. It's necessary to create a watcher script inside of X that `udev` can notify.

- Install `inotify-tools`.
- Create the watcher script.  Set it up to run after the user has logged into X. This can be done via the display manager or desktop environment, depending on whether you want the script running for all users or select users.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  inotifywait -m /tmp |
     while read path action file; do
        if [[ "$file" =~ touchscreen-attach ]] ; then
           [[ "$action" = "OPEN" ]] &&
              sleep 1 &&
              xinput --map-to-output "G2Touch Multi-Touch by G2TSP" DP-1
        fi
     done
  ```
- Use `lsusb` to get the device id of the touch screen. It will be in the form idVendor:idProduct (eg, 2a94:564d).
- Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-touchscreen.rules`:

  ```
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2a94", ATTRS{idProduct}=="564d", RUN+="touch /tmp/touchscreen-attach"
  ```

**See also:**

- [How to execute a shellscript when I plug-in a USB-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65891/how-to-execute-a-shellscript-when-i-plug-in-a-usb-device)
- [How to use inotifywait to watch a directory for creation of files of a specific extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/323901/209257)

---

[JackDaniels points out](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291830/567307) that KDE has input settings associated with Graphic Tablets. They work for my Wacom tablet, but not my laptop touch screen. If this works with your external touch screen, it would be much easier to set up than what I've described above.

[image: KDE Shortcuts]
[image: KDE Settings]
[image: KDE Remap Output]

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing but laptop is touch. Using kubuntu also. If you go into System Settings > Input devices > Graphic Tablet. There you select the tab called "Touch" then the option called "Map Touch Area to Screen". Click on "Toggle Screen" to select which screen you want the touch to be focused. By default it is selected on both screens.

Also you can check this website to create a script that will allow you to automatically select the monitor at startup.

https://networks.guru/2018/11/23/using-dual-monitor-dual-touch-screens-on-ubuntu/

P.S. The script only works when starting up the system. If you disconnect the screen or change to single screen, the touch might revert back to shared. Still trying to figure out how to make the change permanent or modify the script to include screen change and connect/disconnect.

Comment: @JackDaniels, the first part does not work for me, the second part is great for a permanently attached monitor (such as for PC), but for me it's not good as I sometimes detach the second touchscreen and connects it back again. (it's a laptop). After connecting it for the second time without a restart the screen won't work properly until the command will be entered again.
Thank you for your help and all the info!